# Transform Excel Spreadsheet from one format to another

Tags: excel-2010

I have a list of data, that comes from a database that is exportable to excel. But the data comes out looking like this..

```
Room Name   Model_Number   Type
  Name_A      3243234      Projector
  Name_B      3233566      Projector
  Name_C      1232322      Projector
  Name_C      9299393      Camera
  Name_A      9383888      Camera
  Name_B      773984       Camera
  Name_A      875649       Projector
  Name_B      38292A3      Camera
```

What I need is the data to look like this

```
 Room Name  Projector1 Projector2  Camera1   Camera2 
 Name_A     3243234    875649      9383888
 Name_B     3233566                773984    38292A3
 Name_C     1232322                9299393
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish this.. I am thinking I am going to have to write some VB Code that takes each Type column, removes duplicates and then converts the rows into columns into a second spreadsheet then iterate through the Name find the value that matches from the first spread sheet if one exist and then populate the second. Just curious if i am on the write track. ( I haven't done any coding in VB or Excel other than the base stuff, but always willing to learn)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a pivot table very easily - create a new pivot table, select Room_Name as the Row Labels, Type as the Column Labels and Model_Number as the Values.

Comment: So I tried pivot table approach, I will do some research more on pivot tables but what it shows in values when I first tried this method was numbers like 1 and 0, what  I want to see is the actual model numbers rather than a 1 or 0.